# Why can't I use instanceof to determine whether an element is an instance of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know what is it that React does behind the scenes which makes an object that represents a DOM node for a component *not* be an instance of the function which created it.

Why does React use a `type` property instead of prototypes?

i.e.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Parent</div>
  }
}

const instance = <Parent />

console.log(instance instanceof Parent); // False
console.log(instance.type === Parent); // True
console.log(instance.prototype === Parent) // False
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write a JSX, like

```
const instance = <Parent />
```

it gets transpiled to `React.createElement(Parent, {});` which returns just an object

You can log and see the response on `instance`. It is as shown in the image below

[image]

Now this object `isn't an instance of Parent` but has a type property set to Parent

However if you write

```
const instance = new Parent();
```

and then if you check

```
 console.log(instance instanceof Parent); // true
```

This returns true since now `instance` is an instance of Parent